# ember.js ember-data initiale state of new created model record

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Ember.data 2.2.0

The state of just created object is dirty (get('hasDirtyAttributes' return true), cause the new ID is set every time.

I need to know when the record is created, not saved and the "user" not modified it. So, I can't use the dirty state cause the store change it.

If I modified the internal state just after create the record, I will broke somthing inner the record?

My real need, is when I create the record I need a initiale state and I want detect when a user change it. So, I saw in the record source code, it's use the "setProperties" methode to set the ID and optionaly the data passed to the createRecord method.

So, I want override the createRecord store metod to set the dirty state to false after created it. And the principal, how I can do that?

I saw the doc of DS.RootState Class and it just talk about that states : (deleted, saved, uncommitted, inFlight, empty, loaded, created, updated, loading) and the method translateTo but nothing to change the dirty state.

In the doc say :

> Flags are Boolean values that can be used to introspect a record's
>   current state in a more user-friendly way than examining its state
>   path

So... I set currentState.parentState.isDirty to false and that it

**Edit:** After set the flag directly, the record doesn't change state, stay in no dorty. So, how what I can do?

Comment: If you create the record, you can use the `isNew` state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I found is test if the object is new. If is it, re-create a new one.

If not, I call the rollbackAttributes().

And use the that method on model for detect a change :

```
isChanged : function() {
            return this._internalModel.hasChangedAttributes();
        }
```